# ¿Es posible cambiar o actualizar datos en un archivo serializado (.ser) en Java?

Tags: java, lista, serializacion

Tengo un archivo serializado en dónde escribo los datos provenientes de ArrayList contenidas en otros ArrayList, es decir, es cada nodo de la lista principal `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`   se encuentra una sublista `ArrayList<String>` . Tengo mi funcion que serializa y deserializa, pero necesito en cierto punto de mi programa cambiar datos de este archivo .ser. Este cambio será en ocasiones especiales ya que no es lo más óptimo estar cambiando la información a cada rato. Mis opciones en mente son:

✓Ir recorriendo el archivo hasta encontrar un Match para luego crear otro archivo con la información cambiada (esta es la que menos me gusta ya que no quiero estar creando archivos y destruyendo los anteriores)

✓Utilizar el método .replace de StringBuffered pero no sé cómo manejar muy bien esta clase.

También tengo en mis sublistas elementos que representan el String de un int (trate de utilizar una clase propia que me diferencie estos datos pero el método .add no me permitía añadir elementos distintos de String, ArrayList, etc)... Entonces como son distintos datos pensé en utilizar un método genérico.

¿Es posible esto que quiero hacer?
¿Que me recomiendan? Y si es una de mis opciones ¿Algún consejo para hacerlas factibles?
Apenas estoy empezando a trabajar con Java y serialización. Gracias de antemano.

Adjunto una imagen referencial a mí estructura, por requerimiento de mi código, todas las sublistas poseen la misma estructura, y tienen los valores en el mismo orden y todos existen así que iterar en ellas es igual, solo cambian los valores (uno es "Juan" y el otro es "Pedro") [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]